# .withColumn is not giving original columns of the dataframe but only the newly added column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
val withOneDayts=userDataFrame.join(articleDataFrame,userDataFrame("cid")===articleDataFrame("id"),"left").drop(articleDataFrame("id")).drop(articleDataFrame("published_at"))
val frame = withOneDayts.withColumn("views", getViews(withOneDayts("timestamp"), withOneDayts("oneDay_ts"))).groupBy("cid").agg(sum("views"))
val with15MinViews = withOneDayts.withColumn("views", getViews(withOneDayts("timestamp"), withOneDayts("15_min_ts"))).groupBy("cid").agg(sum("views")).withColumnRenamed("sum(views)","views_in_15_min").drop("15_min_ts")
val with30MinViews = with15MinViews.withColumn("views",getViews(with15MinViews("timestamp"),with15MinViews("30_min_ts"))).groupBy("cid").agg(sum("views")).withColumnRenamed("sum(views)","views_in_30_min").drop("30_min_ts")
```

I am trying to get views in first 15 minutes and 30 minutes after the article is published . But for 30 min views it is giving error "Can not resolve "timestamp" among [cid,views_in_15_min]"

Comment: can you share the schema of `withOneDayts` dataframe?

Comment: cid:  String,
uid: String,
eid: String,
merchantId: String,
ip: String,
event: String,
timestamp: Long,
eventType: String,
pageViewEventId: String, 15_min_ts : Long, 30_min_ts: Long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the fourth line where you have used dataframe `with15MinViews` which does not contain the field `timestamp`

```
val with30MinViews = with15MinViews.withColumn("views",
      getViews(with15MinViews("timestamp"),with15MinViews("30_min_ts"))
    )  
    .groupBy("cid").agg(sum("views"))
    .withColumnRenamed("sum(views)","views_in_30_min")
.drop("30_min_ts")
```

The `with15MinViews` dataframe contains only the columns that are used on `groypBy` and `aggregation`. So it contains only `cid`, `views_in_15_min`

I hope this helps!

Comment: So if I need timestamp column in all the three dataframe what should I do ?

Comment: One option is to create a new df with id and timestamp and join. Other option will be using Window which preserves all the columns. If you have same timestamp for each group than you can use any aggregate functions like `first` `max` `min` etc